# I tried to use xubuntu with compiz , i see a different decoration theme (very transparent) that leave TRACES all over the desktop and its annoying?

Tags: compiz

I tried to use xubuntu with compiz , i see a different decoration theme (very transparent) that leave TRACES all over the desktop and its annoying !!

I must have installed compiz cause if else i have tearing on video playback !
i start compiz with the command  compiz --replace

Right now i have ubuntu 11.10 installed but if you know the answer i would be glad to move to something much lighter and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compositing options are disabled when Compiz is used.  Compiz in Xfce needs a window decorator.  Either compile and install Emerald from source http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11401326 and look on gnome-look.org for compiz/beryl themes (my personal fave is DarkAndNameless), or use gtk-window-decorator like so
Using compizconfig-settings-manager, select Window Decoration and change to gtk-window-decorator ---replace --metacity-theme=Ambiance

Answer (score 0):

I use :

```
gtk-window-decorator ---replace --metacity-theme greybird
```

leaving out the "="